# how to type useSearchParams hook when passing it to props or function argument?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks

I use useSearchParams hook in my component
when i pass hook to props or function argument i can't type parameters

```
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
const urlSearchParamState = useSearchParams();
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = urlSearchParamState;
```

How to import types from hook?

```
export declare function useSearchParams(defaultInit?: URLSearchParamsInit): [URLSearchParams, SetURLSearchParams];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URLSearchParams` already exists as a built-in. To get the setter, we can use [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypetype) and access the second element of the returned tuple:

```
type SetURLSearchParams = ReturnType<typeof useSearchParams>[1];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgVwM4FMDK6CGUDGAFgAp44ipwC+cAZlBCHAORS74wC0DyM6UnACaNmAbgCwAKHwQAdqnjIoAG2x4ipKOUwwcfOAF4UGNQRJkKACgCUE6XIVwA2hnXmtFADRwMMUxotUAF1DFBV-d21dPjspGABPMHQ4bBgAVQAlABkIzXJKIwz0GCVZABVE9AAeBKSIWmMsXDM8igA+JwBGINEgA)